# Account not getting logged out completely and still logs in automatically

Tags: discussion, support, auto-login

At work, I logged into Stack Overflow once on the computer of one of my colleagues.

Before I left his machine, I logged out, however, every since then, when my colleague visits Stack Overflow, my account is automatically logged in.

Why is this happening and what I can I do to fix this so I stop getting logged in on his computer?

Comment: Are you sharing a single machine with others?

Comment: No, they are on other machine. I've different machine. I've to go on their seat to logout this. Is this bug of Stackoverflow?

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms you're observing in a bit more detail then? What specifically do you see that tells you you're logged into the systems of other employees?

Comment: Wild guess at problem: Shared IP addresses?

Comment: I mean I created the account of Stackoverflow on my system (A) and I generally login from my system but sometime it login from the other system automatically as well for ex (B,C).

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh Both have different ip address.

Comment: @Williams your bounty message is slightly different than your original question.  Your original question suggests this is a widespread issue and everyone is getting logged into others accounts that have been logged in on other machines.  However, the bounty message suggests it is just 1 account (yours) remainined logged in on 1 other machine.  Which is it?

Comment: I meant completely which I said in the original question.

Comment: @Williams ok, so you have multiple computers that automatically get logged with accounts of other users that have never used that specific computer?

Comment: I have a my account and my system in my LAN. I logged one time my SO account in my friend system and log out also after that. Then Still it automatically logged in my friend system.

Comment: @Williams your question does not say that at all... the fact that you logged in previously to that machine is extremely important, and the fact it is only 1 other system is extremely important.  Sorry, I'm not trying to be critical or anything, I'm just trying to make sure the issue is clear

Comment: hmm I covered all in my question. I did not get you clearly.and What you mean of `Your original question suggests this is a widespread issue`

Comment: @Williams by "widespread" I mean that it happens with multiple user's accounts and multiple computers.  Basically when you open Stack Overflow, you don't know who's account in your network is going to get logged in.

Comment: Why it so . It make my account unsecure such that my enemy friend where I logged last and logout after that can use my account

Comment: @Williams I'm not saying it is so, I am asking.

Comment: @Williams so what is happening?  Is it: "you logged into your friend's computer once, and then you automatically get logged in when your friend goes to Stack Overflow".  Or is it: "many of the users in your company get logged into other user's accounts when they access Stack Overflow even when they have never used the other computer"

Comment: @psubsee2003 you logged into your friend's computer once, and then you automatically get logged in when your friend goes to Stack Overflow-This is happening

Answer (score 4):

If you log in on a machine that someone else might use, you have to remember to log out of both Stack Exchange *and* whatever provider you used to authenticate. So you'd log out of Stack Exchange and then...

- ...If you clicked "Log in with Stack Exchange" to log in, you'd go to [Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) to log out.
- ...If you clicked "Log in with Google" to log in, you'd go to [Google](http://google.com) to log out.
- ...If you clicked "Log in with Yahoo" to log in, you'd go to [Yahoo](http://yahoo.com) to log out.
- ...et cetera. Whatever you used to log in with, you'll have to visit *their* website and log out once you're done.

If you don't do this, the next person to use the machine *might* find himself logged in as you.

A simpler way to avoid trouble when logging in on someone else's machine is to just use their browser's "private" or "incognito" mode, and close the window once you're done. This shouldn't retain any login information for any sites you visit locally, and thus avoids the whole problem.

Comment: Both person are on different machine. I'm on my machine and second person on the different machine still Stackoverflow login into my account automatically on the second person machine

Comment: You might want to talk to your network administrator then; it's possible you have a badly configured caching proxy.

Comment: Both are on different public ipaddress. Both are at different work place location. Suppose I'm at A location and Other is B location. It might i logged into SO from the B location as well but after that I log out but it still login into their automatically. There is no such caching proxy

Comment: If you're *ever* logging into a machine that someone else might use, pay close attention to this answer - it's quite likely you didn't log out when you thought you did. If you've *never* logged into a machine and someone else using it is finding themselves logged in as you, then it is very likely something is broken on the network in between both machines and the site.

Comment: I'm confirmed that I've logout from there

Comment: Your answer did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Williams: I've removed your bounty, as there's really nothing more I can do to help you. You have both Google and [Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) credentials - make sure you've logged off *both* of those services *and* logged out of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep, I logged off Google. Because I use only Google to log in on Stack Overflow. but still problem persist.

Comment: In the past, you've used both Google and SE's OpenID. So you could still be logged in with either. @Williams.

Comment: No, I did not use SE Open Id ever

Comment: Follow [the instructions here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/how-can-i-remotely-log-out-of-gmail) to make sure you're logged out of Google everywhere, @William.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I overcome this limitation, is to always as a rule use a private browsing session when using someone else's machine. It might be slightly uncomfortable (if your workflow is using browser tabs in single window only), but otherwise works perfectly fine.

Conversely, when someone else uses my system, I make sure they are using a private session, so that whatever auto-fill and history settings I have don't capture that user's data.

Comment: But Here How can I stop which is happening. When My friend goes to SO then my account automatically logged in the friend PC. I can follow your tips ahead

Comment: For this one time, clear all cookies from the browser for stackexchange and stackoverflow (assuming these are the only 2 sites you visited). The browser still has the urls visited, so the history is not affected.

Comment: I did all those but still It logged my account in my friend PC

Comment: Just double check again, there might be some cookie left for one of the stackexchange network sites which is doing it.

Comment: I checked it more than 10 times and having same issue